# Can somebody explain this Scala code?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and found this code in the book's source code but no actual explanation for it in the book. I removed details for the sake of simplicity.

```
trait RefModel {
  type Instrument = String
  type Account = String
}

trait ExecutionModel {this: RefModel =>
  case class Execution(account: Account, instrument: Instrument)
}
```

I'm wondering what this `this: RefModel =>` is and what this suppose to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `trait ExecutionModel` need to **compose** `RefModel` when **initiate** `ExecutionModel` class. and This term called **self type**, it means `ExecutionModel` need a `RefModel` for this class.

it's often used by **cake pattern** for **Dependency injection**. so you can use it like:

```
object Foo extends ExecutionModel with RefModel // when initiate **ExecutionMode** bind with **RefModel**
```

Document: [Cake Pattern](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)

Answer (score 1):

It's referred to as a "self type" meaning that the self (this) has to be the specified type as well as being the type (class or trait) being defined.

Think of it as an instruction to the compiler: Don't allow this trait (`ExecutionModel`) to be instantiated unless `RefModel` is included in the mixin. It means that members of `RefModel` are available to the `ExecutionModel` definition code.